# check if connection close between rabbit mq and node js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am able to connect rabbit mq exchange with my `node.js server`. But if I manually delete exchange from Rabbit MQ UI, then is there any way to check from `node.js` that the exchanged is deleted or `connection` is closed.

Because on publishing message on same exchange, `node.js` crashes and i am not able to handle `exception` using `try catch`. I want to recreate exchange from `node.js` after handling `exception`.

```
exchange.publish(ROUTING_KEY, msg);  //here exchange is already deleted so throwing below error 

    Error: NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'lutron.poc.incoming' in vhost '/'
    at Exchange._onMethod (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutroncloudserverco
nnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:2091:15)
    at Exchange.Channel._onChannelMethod (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutr
oncloudserverconnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:1533
:14)
    at Connection._onMethod (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutroncloudserver
connector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:1056:28)
    at AMQPParser.self.addListener.parser.onMethod (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_G
ITnew\lutroncloudserverconnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\am
qp.js:895:12)
    at AMQPParser._parseMethodFrame (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutronclo
udserverconnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:449:10)
    at frameEnd (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutroncloudserverconnector\lu
troncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:190:16)
    at frame (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutroncloudserverconnector\lutro
ncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:175:14)
    at AMQPParser.header [as parse] (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutronclo
udserverconnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:162:14)
    at AMQPParser.execute (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutroncloudserverco
nnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:234:21)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (F:\workspaces\LutronHeroku_GITnew\lutroncloudserv
erconnector\lutroncloudserverconnector\node_modules\amqp\amqp.js:932:12)
Server: worker 4028  died; signal null
```

Is there a way to catch this `exception`?

Comment: Could you add some code showing how you tried to catch the exception?

Comment: try {  
  exchange.publish(ROUTING_KEY, msg);
 } catch (e) {
  console.log('error publishing message', e);
  createExchange();
  publish(serverInstanceId, msg);
 }
Thanks gnat for your reply.